# How to use fragments in an activity which already extends another class?

Tags: java, android, fragment

To use fragments in an activity, we need to extend `Fragment` in that activity. But my activity already extends another class, and java cannot extend 2 classes. So how to use fragments inside an activity that already extends another class?

Comment: Have a Fragment object inside your own object and invoke the methods you need.

Comment: I can't see any solution if your base Activity is not a FragmentActivity.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ahh so easy! Write it down as the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: rciovati The first commenter's solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple inheritance (more than one parent class) was tried in C++ and gave some interesting challenges, so the Java designers decided to try "interfaces" instead.

For your actual problem, have a Fragment object inside your own object and invoke the methods you need.

Comment: Using this method is giving me a nullPointerException at `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`

Comment: You need to assign it a value.

Comment: I have given it a value, as you can see below. The `fragmenttrans` class extends `Fragment`, but the rest of the class is empty.

`fragmenttrans ft=new fragmenttrans();
        
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ft.getFragmentManager();
         fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = new Myfragment1();
  fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "MYLIST");
  fragmentTransaction.commit();`

Comment: Put code in your original question instead of in comments.  Also, exactly WHAT variable was null to trigger the exception?

Comment: Getting nullpointerexception in this line : `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`, so I guess the variable `fragmentTransaction` was null

Comment: No. FragmentManager is null.  How can it be that?

Comment: The `fragmenttrans` class is empty. Could that be why?